# Automating tick box in form filing through VBA

Tags: html, vba, automation

I am trying to automate filing a web form through VBA. I am stuck at point where I have to tick a tick box in the form before proceeding. Below is my HTML code for tick box

```
<input name="ConfirmExcludedBreeds" id="ConfirmExcludedBreeds" aria-required="true" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Please correct the VBA code I am using for the tick box

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("ConfirmExcludedBreeds").Click
```

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide minimal working example to lead to your error. This helps to convice people to help you faster and better. Now you risk heavily downvoting and the change of  question removed.

Answer (score 0):

`ie.document.getElementsByName("ConfirmExcludedBreeds")` will return a 0 based collection of elements with the specified className. You would need to specify the index for the element of interest e.g.

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("ConfirmExcludedBreeds")(0).Click
```

Or, use the `id` that is present that should return one element.

```
ie.document.getElementById("ConfirmExcludedBreeds").Click
```